# PHP $_POST Validation

Tags: php, validation, post, conditional-statements

Is there a quick and easy way to check if any of my $_POST data has the same value?

I need it as a conditional statement...

Example:

```
$week1 = $_POST['Week_1'];
$week2 = $_POST['Week_2'];
$week3 = $_POST['Week_3'];
$week4 = $_POST['Week_4'];
$week5 = $_POST['Week_5'];
$week6 = $_POST['Week_6'];
$week7 = $_POST['Week_7'];
$week8 = $_POST['Week_8'];
$week9 = $_POST['Week_9'];
$week10 = $_POST['Week_10'];
$week11 = $_POST['Week_11'];
$week12 = $_POST['Week_12'];
$week13 = $_POST['Week_13'];
$week14 = $_POST['Week_14'];
$week15 = $_POST['Week_15'];
$week16 = $_POST['Week_16'];
$week17 = $_POST['Week_17'];
```

If the values of any of the weeks = equal the value of any of the other weeks, error...

Is there a quick way to do this in PHP?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Sort the values, then finding duplicates is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only `$_POST` values you have are `'Week_1'` through `'Week_17'` then

```
if (count(array_unique($_POST))  ===  count($_POST)) {
  //all unique values, do stuff...
}
```

Comment: So my else on that if statement would be my error message (assuming there are two alike values)

Answer (score 2):

first though to pop in to my head:

```
$r=array_unique(array($week1, ...));
 if (count($r) !=17){

//error
}
```

Comment: his is good to, if you don't have to specify what values in $_POST you want to check

Comment: True, for my purposes, I will take your answer. Because I am unsure at this point in time if I will need to add more POSTS or not... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the pairs and compare them:

```
  $weeks=array();

   foreach(range(1,17) as $i)
   {
     array_push($weeks,'Week_' . $i);
   }

   foreach(range(1,16) as $i)
   {
     foreach(range($i+1,17) as $j)
       {
         if($_POST[$weeks[$i]]==$_POST[$weeks[$j]])
           {
             die("Rut-roh!");
           {
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: This look's right, I was thinking of a FOREACH loop myself, but I think the other posts are more efficient, no?

Comment: Well, under the hood, I suspect the other solutions implement a `foreach` loop to gather the unique values.  And while it may be a more compact solution, I personally like to use relatively simple loops like this instead of `yet_another_inconsistently_named_PHP_function()` (or, wait, was it `yet_another_inconsistently_named_PHPfunction()`?......).  

Anyways, as they say in the Perl community, TIMTOWTDI (there is more than one way to do it).